# Why does changing the format of a video change its pixel values?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have built a software that analyzes videos using OpenCV and C++, but I've recently noticed a weird ambiguity:

I have two versions of the same video, an MP4 and an AVI converted using an online tool. If I feed both the video files into OpenCV (as VideoCapture objects) and, before any processing at all, if I simply output the value of a certain pixel at (x,y), the pixel values do not match.

**Sample code:**

```
    VideoCapture cap(filename);

    if (!cap.isOpened()) return;

    //Load a frame
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame;
    std::cout << frame.at<Vec3b>(316,316)[0] << std::endl;
```

**Output for AVI:**

```
176
```

**Output for MP4:**

```
159
```

This is problematic for my software and is a curious result. I've noticed that the decompression type of the video changes from cvid (in the AVI) to avc1 (in the MP4).

What is the explanation for these ambiguities and how would someone building video analysis software counteract them?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression

Comment: A quick Google search suggests that cvid is the Cinepak codec, see: https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000062.shtml.  Looks like your online tool thought it was a good bet.

Comment: To answer how to make your software robust to these differences, we'll need some more information. What video analysis techniques are you performing that are so sensitive to this? What methods of adding numeric tolerance are known for that technique and have you tried them? Have you considered using uncompressed video?

Comment: Different compression algorithms. Different absolute pixel values. Unless you use *lossless* compression, the end result *is* going to be different.

Comment: @alterigel My technique involves converting RGB values of pixels to some other quantity and using a summed-area table to check if the average quantity is above a certain threshold. The software detects certain features in video.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is acctually curious. The changing values is due to the codifications used to compres the raw video. MP4 use h.264 and AVI uses xvid. The way that every frame I, B and P is processes is slightly different and that make the data in every pixel change a bit.

Comment: .mp4 and .avi as file extensions refer to container format, and there exist codecs, (codificators, you call them), that can be packed both to .avi and .mp4. (Say MPEG-4 Video)